# javascript replace string (Regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex, audio

I am trying to replace string

```
 <audio controls src='tempfile://b07b4667-62d6-432d-2dd7-feedd9255ea3'>
```

with empty using regular expression

I tried this way but it doenst work..
Here link is the audio string which i want to replace with empty..

```
return text.replace(/<\s*audio[^>]*>\s*<\s*\/\s*audio\s*>/ig, function (whole, a, b, c) {
            if (b == link) return '';
            else return whole;
        });
```

Comment: You mean `var audio = document.querySelector("audio");  audio.parentNode.removeChild(audio);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like the following way *(using regex [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html))* :

```js
var str = "<audio controls src='tempfile://b07b4667-62d6-432d-2dd7-feedd9255ea3'>";
var emptyStr = str.replace(/([<\s\w='://\->])/ig, '');
console.log(emptyStr);
```

Comment: i just used regex = /<\s*audio[^>]*>\s*/; to identify string " <audio controls src='tempfile://b07b4667-62d6-432d-2dd7-feedd9255ea3'>
"  and replace with empty and it works..

Comment: @user2732812 the one I gave works too. simple and efficient. :-)